# bayesian test of linear regression hypothesis

Tags: self-study, bayes

write program bayesian test of linear regression hypothesis In R or winbugs :

```
h (θi)= µi
βi~exp-family      except Normal distribution
H0 : µi=α+β1x1+ β2x2
H1 : µi=α+β1x1
```

(B.F12 = (m(x|μ_2))/(m(x|μ_1)) )=???

Comment: This seems like a homework problem. If it is, please add the `homework` tag so that we can treat it accordingly. Also add some comments on how you've tried to solve the problem and where you got stuck.

Comment: There's also no need to email users of Stack Exchange sites asking them for an answer. After I got your email, the first thing I did was search Google for "bayesian test of linear regression hypothesis" and this question was in the top 5.